# How to know how many items a Firestore query will return while implementing pagination

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore has this guide on how to paginate a query:

[**Firestore - Paginate data with query cursors**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors)

They show the following example:

> **Paginate a query**
>
> Paginate queries by combining query cursors with the limit() method. For example, use the last document in a batch as the start of a cursor for the next batch.
>
> ```
> var first = db.collection("cities")
>        .orderBy("population")
>        .limit(25);
>
> return first.get().then(function (documentSnapshots) {
>  // Get the last visible document
>  var lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length-1];
>  console.log("last", lastVisible);
>
>  // Construct a new query starting at this document,
>  // get the next 25 cities.
>  var next = db.collection("cities")
>          .orderBy("population")
>          .startAfter(lastVisible)
>          .limit(25);
> });
> ```

**QUESTION**

I get the example, but how can I know how many items (in total, without the limit restriction) that query will return? I'll need that to calculate the number of pages and control the pagination component, won't I?

I can't simply display next and back buttons without knowing the limit.

How is it supposed to be done? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't know the size of the result set in advance.  You have to page through all the results to get the total size.  This is similar to not being able to know the size of a collection without also recording that yourself somewhere else - it's just not scalable to provide this information, in the way that Cloud Firestore needs to scale.

Comment: If I page through all I'll be basically reading (and paying to read) all the documents, right? One way would be to keep track of the existence of 1 previous and 1 next page, to at least disable the buttons. This seems like a common use case (like numbering the pages and showing search results number). Have you seen any examples of how people get around this limitation? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you would have to read all the documents. You will have to come up with a trade-off the you find acceptable for your specific needs.

Answer (score 1):

this is not possible, the iterator cannot know how many documents it contains, as they are fetched via a gRPC stream.

But there is a workaround... but you have to make a few stuff:

1) write a counter in a firebase doc, which you increment or decrement everything you make a transaction

2) store the count in a field of your new entry, like `position` 10 or something.

Then you create an index on that field (position DESC).

This way you can do a skip+limit with a where("position", "<", N).orderBy("position", DESC)

It's complex but it does the trick

Comment: Thanks! But in this case you're assuming that I'm querying a full collection for all documents without any `where` clauses, right? What if I'm filtering for some documents that meet a specific criteria?